# Know which button pressed led to this page

Tags: javascript, html

I have a menu with ~6 buttons, each that lead to the same page. 
In that page, there is a drop down menu. 
The purpose of the 6 buttons is that when one of those buttons is clicked, the page is redirected, and then the drop down menu opens to the correct tab.

However, all scripts are killed when a page is redirected, so I cant do something like this:

```
<body>
<a id="buttonID" onclick="GoToPage('buttonID')">All</a>
</body>

<script>
function GoToPage(buttonID){
    redirect to page.html;
    open menu to tab related to buttonID
}
</script>
```

Instead I would probably have to create a function that executes when the page loads, and then attempts to find from which button did it get there from, and opens the menu to the correct configuration based on that.

Should I use something like:

```
window.onload = ....
```

And how would I be able to pass which button redirected the page to this?

Comment: You can have pass the button ID as a query parameter. Something like, window.location = 'https://yoursite.com?button=buttonID'. You can capture button params value at the server and render appropriately

Answer (score 0):

Opening the dropdown menu should be the responsibility of the destination page, not the source page. Since the server doesn't care about the dropdown menu state, send that information in the [fragment identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier):

```
<a id="buttonID" href="page.html#all">All</a>
```

On the receiving end, you can retrieve the identifier with

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  let target = window.location.hash; // target = "#all"
  // modify your menu as appropriate
});
```

The `load` event doesn't fire until the page has completely finished loading: images, stylesheets, everything. Modifying the dropdown menu doesn't require any of that, so use the [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) event instead. It fires when the HTML page has been loaded and parsed and is ready for DOM manipulation.

Comment: You are a homie my dude. I didn't know about window.location.hash. I started html/css/javascript last night and this problem really threw a wrench into my progress.